# Nightwatch.js - Can I have multiple folders for Custom Commands?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm fairly new at automated testing and setting up Nightwatch but I can already tell my Custom Commands folder is going to get unwieldy sooner or later. I've seen some example nightwatch.json files that use an array for the Custom Commands Path but I can seem to figure it out. Is it possible? Are the examples I've seen out of date?

Here's what I'm attempting to define in nightwatch.json:

```
"custom_commands_path" : [
    "./custom-commands/", 
    "./custom-commands/login-signup/"
],
```

If I place my "loginFromHomepage" custom command file in the `/custom-commands` folder it'll run just fine. If I move the file to `/custom-commands/login-signup` I get an error stating that the "loginFromHomepage" commands doesn't exist.

What am I missing or not understanding here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I normally separate my pages by folders. Try something like this

```
  "custom_commands_path": [
     "./customCommands/folder1",
     "./customCommands/folder2",
     "./customCommands/folder"
    ],
```

Comment: normally asking it out loud creates the solution itself, thanks you just helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

I just realized this was a problem with our setup. For some reason our runner.js file was looking at nightwatch.json AND nightwatch-dev.json for the nightwatchConfig.

I'm not clear on why we're using both but it appears my issue was because I was only adding the additional folders for the custom commands to nightwatch.json and not nightwatch-dev.json.